# How do you set the tab/focus order in a angular reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core, vmware-clarity

I have a Clarity Wizard with a reactive Form and want to know how to set the tab/focus order of the form, because my tab disappears when on certain elements in the form and i don't know why.

So i was wondering how to set the order in code?

I have tried using the nativeElement.focus() with a @ViewChild method but this didn't help with my problem the tab still disappears.

**HTML of the elements where the tab disappears**

```
<clr-input-container>
       <label>Family Number</label>
       <input clrInput type="text" (blur)="ValidateEzcapMemb()" formControlName="ezcapmemb"
              required />
       <clr-control-error>{{this.errorMsgMemb}}</clr-control-error>
       <clr-control-helper style="color:rgb(4, 161, 70)">{{this.errorMsgMemb}}</clr-control-helper>
     </clr-input-container>
     <clr-input-container>
       <label>Depedent Code</label>
       <input clrInput type="text" (blur)="ValidateEzcapDep()"  formControlName="ezcapdepmemb"
              required />
       <clr-control-error>{{this.errorMsgDepMem}}</clr-control-error>
       <clr-control-helper style="color:rgb(4, 161, 70)">{{this.errorMsgDepMem}}</clr-control-helper>
     </clr-input-container>
```

**Methods That fires on blur**

```
  ValidateEzcapMemb() {
    this.errorMsgMemb = 'Checking...';
    console.log("member no blur :" + this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapmemb').value);
    this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.currentClaimHeader.EZCAPMEMB = this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapmemb').value;
    this.errorMsgMemb = this.FieldValidation(this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.currentClaimHeader.EZCAPMEMB, 'ezcapmemb');
    if (this.errorMsgMemb === 'valid') {
      this.errorMsgMemb = this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.DataBaseCheckEzcapMemb();
      if (this.errorMsgMemb !== 'Family Number is incorrect') {
        this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapmemb').setErrors(null);
        if ((this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapdepmemb').value !== null) && (this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapdepmemb').value !== '')
          && (this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapdepmemb').value !== undefined)) {
          this.ValidateEzcapDep();
        }
      } else {
        this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapmemb').setErrors(this.errorMsgMemb);
      }
    } 
  }

  ValidateEzcapDep() {
    this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.currentClaimHeader.EZCAPMEMB = this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapmemb').value;
  this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.currentClaimHeader.membDepCode = this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapdepmemb').value;
   this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.currentClaimHeader.EZCAPMEMB = this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.currentClaimHeader.EZCAPMEMB + '-' + this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.currentClaimHeader.membDepCode;
    this.errorMsgDepMem = this.FieldValidation(this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.currentClaimHeader.EZCAPMEMB, 'ezcapdepmemb');
    if ((this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapmemb').value === '') || (this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapmemb').value === null)) {
      this.errorMsgDepMem = this._errorMsg['familyNumber'];
      this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapdepmemb').setErrors(this.errorMsgDepMem);
    } else {
      if (this.errorMsgDepMem === 'valid')
      this.errorMsgDepMem = this._appService.ClaimCaptureService.DataBaseCheckEzcapDepMemb();
      if (this.errorMsgDepMem !== 'Dependant Number is incorrect') {
        this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapdepmemb').setErrors(null);
      } else {
        this.cMasterForm.get('ezcapdepmemb').setErrors(this.errorMsgMemb);
      }
    }
  }
```

**How my Form is Declared in ngOnInit() method**

```
    this.cMasterForm = this.fb.group({
      provclaim: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      ezcapauth: ['', [Validators.maxLength(16)]],
      ezcapprov: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      ezcapmemb: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      ezcapdepmemb: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      reprovider: ['', [Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      vendoid: [],
      PHC: [],
      PlaceSelect: [],
      CTOpt: [],
      HPCode: [],
      RecDateField: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

When you get to the Family Number field and you press tab to go to the next field which would be the dependent code field, but instead of it doing that when you press tab the tab just disappears.

**Here is a Visuale Example of What the Wizard Looks like**
*(I marked the two fields in green where the tab disappears)*
[image: Visual Example]

Comment: Can you provide an isolated example of this problem? I'm not exactly sure what is happening from the snippets and image. Also where are the tabs?

Comment: @Jeremy Wilken--- What i meant by tabs is when your focus is set on a element on the form and you press the tab button on your keyboard the focus is on the next element on the form, but when the focus is on the Family Number Element in the form and i press the tab button the focus just completely disappears from the form.

Comment: Since you've implemented things in a certain way, its hard to guess without a small demo to view. When focus goes to the body, this is because you try to move focus to something incorrectly, but I can't easily diagnose without a Stackblitz demo.